# Using Tailwind (SCSS) with Gatsby

Tags: gatsby, tailwind-css

Does anyone know how to implement Tailwind (using SCSS) with a Gatsby project?

I'm following the [documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/tailwind-css/) and able to get SCSS to work, however the Tailwind classes are not working.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

in gatsby-browser.js `import "./src/styles/tailwind.scss"`